# Cancel part of a single line from specific commit, after git push

Tags: git, version-control, git-push

Someone pushed the following line to our repository:

```
git = ['a', 'w', 'e', 's', 'o', 'm', 'e', BugSyntaxErrorBug]
```

But it actually should be:

```
git = ['a', 'w', 'e', 's', 'o', 'm', 'e']
```

Since than many pushes were made, and I want to rewrite it from this specific push. The idea behind this is that if someone will pull an older version of this code, the code will work.

Thanks :)

Comment: If you just want to undo that one small change, can you do so manually, commit, and push? Or do you want to reset the entire repo to before that commit?

Comment: It's certainly possible.  Have you read through the [Rewriting History](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History) section of the Git Book? That's probably the place to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I would do it.

tag these so you can restore if something goes wrong.

```
git tag MyOldCommit BADCOMMIT
git tag MyOldMaster master
```

if you need to you can recover master unchanged with

```
git branch -f master MyOldMaster
```

now checkout the bad commit to a new branch

```
git checkout -b MyFixedCommit BADCOMMIT
```

after removing the offending bytes, replace the old commmit with new one.

```
git commit --amend -m"my commit message"
```

go back to your old branch master branch

```
git checkout master
```

rebase master (and only master!!!) onto MyFixedCommit

```
git rebase --onto MyFixedCommit BADCOMMIT master
```

git will re-play (commit by commit) the changes from BADCOMMIT to tip of master on to MyfixedCommit.  You will have to resolve any conflicts that Git finds on the way.

!!Since you are re-writing history, the commit chain of master will now be different other user's tags and branches that referenced the old master commit chain!!